# Proving properties of a system containing only two objects (even and odd numbers).

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing

Working on the book: Lange, Serge. "Basic Mathematics" (p. 63, exercise 1).

> 1. Let E be an abbreviation for even, and let I be an abbreviation for odd. We know that:
>
> $$E+E=E\\
> E + I = I + E = I\\
> I + I = E\\
> EE = E\\
> II = I\\
> IE = EI = E$$
>
> a) Show that addition for E and I is associative and commutative. Show that E plays the role of a zero element for addition. What is the additive inverse of E? What is the additive inverse of I?
>
> b) Show that multiplication for E and I is commutative and associative. Which of E or I behaves like 1? Which behaves like 0 for multiplication? Show that multiplication is distributive with respect to addition.

How can I approach this exercise ? Do I need to do an exhaustive proof or I can assume arbitrary elements belong to this system and proceed from there ?

EDIT: Based on the excellent suggestion received, I came up with this proof. Is this approach correct ?

**a)**
**Addition for $E$ and $I$  is associative.**

$
\begin{align*}
(E+E)+E=E+E&=\color{blue}E=E+E=E+(E+E)\\
(E+E)+I=E+I&=\color{blue}I=E+I=E+(E+I)\\
(E+I)+E=I+E&=\color{blue}I=E+I=E+(I+E)\\
(E+I)+I=I+I&=\color{blue}E=E+E=E+(I+I)\\
(I+E)+E=I+E&=\color{blue}I=I+E=I+(E+E)\\
(I+E)+I=I+I&=\color{blue}E=I+I=I+(E+I)\\
(I+E)+I=I+I&=\color{blue}E=I+I=I+(E+I)\\
(I+I)+I=E+I&=\color{blue}I=I+E=I+(I+I)\\
\end{align*}
$

**Addition for $E$ and $I$ is commutative.**

$
\begin{align*}
E+E&=\color{blue}E=E+E\\
E+I&=\color{blue}I=I+E\\
I+E&=\color{blue}I=E+I\\
I+I&=\color{blue}E=I+I\\
\end{align*}
$

**$E$ is the zero element for addition.**

$
E+a=a+E=a\\
\begin{align*}
E+\color{blue}E&=\color{blue}E+E=a\\
E+\color{blue}I&=\color{blue}I+E=a\\
\end{align*}
$

**$E$ is the additive inverse of $E$.**

$
E+a=a+E=a\\
\begin{align*}
E+\color{blue}E=\color{blue}E+E=E
\end{align*}
$

**b)**
**Multiplication for $E$ and $I$  is associative.**

$
\begin{align*}
(EE)E=EE&=\color{blue}E=EE=E(EE)\\
(EE)I=EI&=\color{blue}E=EI=E(EI)\\
(EI)E=IE&=\color{blue}E=EI=E(IE)\\
(EI)I=II&=\color{blue}I=EE=E(II)\\
(IE)E=IE&=\color{blue}E=IE=I(EE)\\
(IE)I=II&=\color{blue}I=II=I(EI)\\
(IE)I=II&=\color{blue}I=II=I(EI)\\
(II)I=EI&=\color{blue}E=IE=I(II)\\
\end{align*}
$

**Multiplication for $E$ and $I$ is commutative.**

$
\begin{align*}
EE&=\color{blue}E=EE\\
EI&=\color{blue}E=IE\\
IE&=\color{blue}E=EI\\
II&=\color{blue}I=II\\
\end{align*}
$

**$I$ is the 1 element for multiplication.**

$
Ia=aI=a\\
\begin{align*}
I\color{blue}E&=\color{blue}EI=\color{blue}E\\
I\color{blue}I&=\color{blue}II=\color{blue}I\\
\end{align*}
$

**$E$ is the zero element for multiplication.**

$
Ea=aE=E\\
\begin{align*}
E\color{blue}E&=\color{blue}EE=\color{blue}E\\
E\color{blue}I&=\color{blue}IE=\color{blue}E\\
\end{align*}
$

**Multiplication is distributive with respect to addition.**

$
\begin{align*}
E(E+E)=EE&=\color{blue}E=E+E=EE+EE\\
E(E+I)=EI&=\color{blue}E=E+E=EE+EI\\
E(I+E)=EI&=\color{blue}E=E+E=EI+EE\\
E(I+I)=EI&=\color{blue}E=E+E=EI+EI\\
I(E+E)=IE&=\color{blue}E=E+E=IE+IE\\
I(E+I)=II&=\color{blue}I=E+I=IE+II\\
I(E+I)=II&=\color{blue}I=I+E=II+IE\\
I(I+I)=IE&=\color{blue}E=I+I=II+II\\
\end{align*}
$

Comment: Yes, you need to do a real proof. Just verify the required properties. You can chose integers as representatives. Do you know what "inverse element" for addition is?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I know what an “inverse element” is.

Comment: You only have a few symbols so do them all.

Comment: If you know this, then what is the additive inverse of $I$ if $I+I=E$?

Comment: Good question. If E is the zero element, I should think $I$ is it’s own inverse ?

Comment: "I should think I is it’s own inverse ?"  Lose the hesitancy and pick a side.  "I is its own inverse"  Say it loud; Say it proud.

Comment: Thanks for the confidence, @fleablood. It’s surprising for me that an object is its own inverse.

Comment: " It’s surprising for me that an object is its own inverse."  Well, zero is its own inverse in the integers.  And $1$ and $-1$ are both their own *multiplicative* inverses.  There's nothing in the definition that says an element can't be it's only inverse.  And if you are dealing with finite groups and fields this will actually become *VERY* common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have 6 equations in the table.  Just do them all:

> a) Show that addition for E and I is associative:

So show $(a+b) + c= a+(b+ c)$.

By considering the eight cases of $a = E,I; b=E,I; c=E,I$.

> and commutative.

So show $a+b = b+a$.

By considering the four cases of $a = E,I; b=E; I$.

(Although there are some logical shortcuts you can take).

> Show that E plays the role of a zero element for addition.

So show $E+a = a+E = a$ by considering the two case $a=E;I$.

> What is the additive inverse of E?

So show there is exactly one element, $a$, where $E+a = a+E = E$.  Do this by looking and the six line table you listed above.

> What is the additive inverse of I?

ditto but for $a+I = I + a = E$.

Comment: Thank you. I will start doing it.

Comment: There are some shortcuts to avoid all *eight* cases of associativity, but I suggest you do all eight cases just to get a very *firm* feeling of what it measn.   $(E+I)+E = I+E =I$ while $E+(I+E)= E+I = I$ so that's *one* case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "assume arbitrary elements belong to this system." There are two, and only two, elements in the system: $E$ and $I$. You should do an exhaustive proof, but it won't be too exhausting: there aren't that many possible additions and multiplications of merely two elements.

Comment: Thank you. For example, if I want to prove $A \subseteq B$, I would assume an arbitrary element $x$ belong to $A$ and proceed from there. Perhaps, my formulation wasn’t clear.

Comment: Sorry, I was giving an example not directly related to the question. Just to clarify what I mean by “arbitrary elements”.

Comment: @F.Zer In this case I don't think Lang means for $E$ and $I$ to be sets -- they are the objects themselves. Is that distinction clear to you?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Yes, I see them as objects.