# Show that addition for odd and even numbers is associative and commutative - Serge Lang Basic Mathematics

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here's a screenshot of the exercise description from Serge Lang Basic Mathematics:

> [image]

I don't quite understand how to show that. My idea so far is to replace $E$ with $2n$ and $I$ with $2n + 1$.

$$E + I = I + E = I$$
$$2a + (2b +1) = (2b + 1) + 2a = \text{odd number}$$
We can group these differently:
$$(2a + 2b) + 1 = 2b + (1 + 2a) = \text{odd number}$$

Could someone give me a hint on how to approach it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving properties of a system containing only two objects (even and odd numbers).](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3684180/proving-properties-of-a-system-containing-only-two-objects-even-and-odd-numbers)

Comment: I don’t think you need to look at actual even and odd numbers. You have a set $\{E,O\}$ and have defined the operators of addition and multiplication on them. They are based on the ideas of even and odd numbers, but you don’t need to know that to prove these facts.

Comment: Thank you for providing me with a link. Looks like I did a pretty bad job searching. I have some additional questions regarding this problem but I guess it's better to ask them directly in a thread with more activity to make searching for others easier? Should I close this duplicate thread?